# How to fetch the '3 bits' field from the below mentioned string format

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit

[image]

Hi,

Say i have string like "888820c8". How do i fetch that 3 bits in an int in c programming language?

UPDATE 1 -

This is what i was able to do

```
static const char* getlast(const char *pkthdr)
{
    const char *current;
    const char *found = NULL;
    const char *target = "8888";
    int index = 0;
    char pcp = 0;

    size_t target_length = strlen(target);
    current = pkthdr + strlen(pkthdr) - target_length;

    while ( current >= pkthdr ) {
        if ((found = strstr(current, target))) {
            printf("found!\n");
            break;
        }
        current -= 1;
    }

    if(found)
    {
        index = found - pkthdr;
        index += 4; /*go to last of 8188*/
    }
    printf("index %d\n", index);
     /* Now how to get the next 3 bits*/

    printf("pkthdr %c\n", pkthdr[index]);

    pcp = pkthdr[index] & 0x7;
    printf("%c\n", pcp);
    return pcp;
}
```

Clearly i know the last part of my program is wrong and any inputs would be helpful. thanks!

Update 2:

Thanks pratik for the pointer.
Does the below code look good now?

```
static char getlast(const char *pkthdr)
{
    const char *current;
    const char *found = NULL;
    const char *tpid = "8188";
    int index = 0;
    char *pcp_byte = 0;
    char pcp = 0;
    int pcp2 = 0;
    char byte[2] = {0};
    char *p;
    unsigned int uv =0 ;

    size_t target_length = strlen(tpid);
    current = pkthdr + strlen(pkthdr) - target_length;
    //printf("current %d\n", current);

    while ( current >= pkthdr ) {
        if ((found = strstr(current, tpid))) {
            printf("found!\n");
            break;
        }
        current -= 1;
    }

    found = found + 4;

    strncpy(byte,found,2);
    byte[2] = '\0';

    uv =strtoul(byte,&p,16);

    uv = uv & 0xE0;
    char i = uv >> 5;
    printf("%d i",i);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: That's not a "string format". But to solve your problem, writing a program would be a good idea. Feel free to ask a **specific** question if that airses. Remember to provide a [mcve] and follow the advice in [ask].

Comment: And "masking" and "bit-shifting" might be a good terms to start your research from.

Comment: If it is in textual format first you can apply `strtol` to convert it to the internal binary representation, and then apply a mask and a shift, or a shift and a mask. But what have you tried? We don't like to post a pat solution where you don't seem to have started.

Comment: You should better formulate your questions.

Comment: something like this `pcp = pkthdr[4] >> 5;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you have locates the character that contains the 3 bits that you want. That character will be a digit (`'0'` thru `'9'`), an uppercase letter (`'A'` thru `'F'`) or a lowercase letter (`'a'` thru `'f'`). So the first task is to convert the character to its numeric equivalent, e.g. like this

```
unsigned int value;
if ( sscanf( &pkthdr[index], "%1x", &value ) != 1 )
{
    // handle error: the character was not a valid hexadecimal digit
}
```

At this point, you have a 4-bit value, but you want to extract the upper three bits. That can be done with shifting and masking, e.g.

```
int result = (value >> 1) & 7;
printf( "%d\n", result );
```

Note that if you want to return the 3-bit number from the function, the function prototype needs to be changed to return an `int`, e.g.

```
static int getlast(const char *pkthdr)
{
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: plus one for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Read this string char array
Char data[8] = "888820c8"
(data[4]&0xe0) >> 5 is your ans

Comment: just no need to use a mask